# How to enable AppInfo without most windows functionality

Tags: windows-10, command-line, services

I am trying to activate AppInfo

I did some empirical changes and deactivated unfortunately-necessary services in taskmanager, when I tried successfully to prevent an automatic windows-un-rollback, but it broke a lot of functionality.

I could just reinstall my OS, but fixing it without a reinstall would probably teach me a lot about the OS I am running on.

My windows 10 version is version 1511 (Build 10586.0)

When I try to open taskmanager or elevated cmd with the power user menu (Windows-Key + X) I receive :

> This File does not have a Program Associated with it for Performing This Action

When I try to :

- open taskmanager any other way
- start elevated cmd (with administrative priviledges)
- open regedit

I receive:

> The service cannot be started, either because it is disabled or because it has no enabled devices associated with it

I can access :

- run prompt
- cmd without administrative priviledges
- control center
- windows explorer
- boot menu etc.

Search is disabled, I can work around that.

I can install some applications, but none that rely on .net

when I try `sc config AppInfo start= auto` in cmd w/o administrative priviledges I receive:

> [SC] OpenService failed 5 : access is denied

same with `net user administrator /active:yes` :

> system error 5 access is denied

Any thoughts on how to enable AppInfo?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have done quite a few changes in Windows.
The best solution would be to undo them all.

You could do that by rolling back Windows to a System restore from before
doing all these changes.

See the article
[How to Do a System Restore of Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4588-system-restore-windows-10-a.html).

Once everything is working again, you could Start/Stop the Application Identity
service from applet `Services.msc`, also accessible from
*Administrative Tools > Services".

You could read more about it in the article:
[Configure the Application Identity service](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-defender-application-control/applocker/configure-the-application-identity-service).

As another remark, Windows 10 build 10586 (version 1511) dates from November 2015.
Running such an old version is strongly not recommended.
You are missing quite a lot of protections and new features.

Comment: My only restore point is the one I used for the rolllback I cannot go further back.

Comment: as for services.msc that falls into the "The service cannot be started, ..." category.

Comment: In this case I don't see another solution than an [In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html). Doing that will also upgrade you to the latest Windows version. But as there is such a large difference in versions, be prepared with good backups if the worse happens.

Comment: I've tried out a newer windows version, because I was intrigued by the native bash shell. But as that machine is primarily used for testing my software, it does not require an internet connection and is therefore fairly safe. I did the rollback when I noticed distracting GUI changes and general changes resulting in destruction of workflow options, along with an unnecessary performance hit.

Comment: The second link doesn't work on my device, which is windows "home", which does not have gpmp.msc and the workaround ```pushd "%~dp0"
dir /b %SystemRoot%\servicing\Packages\Microsoft-Windows-GroupPolicy-ClientExtensions-Package~3*.mum >List.txt
dir /b %SystemRoot%\servicing\Packages\Microsoft-Windows-GroupPolicy-ClientTools-Package~3*.mum >>List.txt
for /f %%i in ('findstr /i . List.txt 2^>nul') do dism /online /norestart /add-package:"%SystemRoot%\servicing\Packages\%%i"``` requires administrative priviledges

Comment: Application Identity service is for using AppLocker which is not available on Windows Home. Modifying Windows is impossible without Admin permissions. I'm greatly puzzled by your last comment.

Comment: In my question I've stated, that I do not have administrative priviledges.

Comment: I'm sorry, I still don't have a grip on your situation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100335/discussion-between-s3k-and-harrymc).